# Removing duplicates from column - Exclude top row from getDataRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to remove duplicate rows based on column 1. This is working correctly, however I want to exclude the header rows from this.

The reason for wanting to exclude the header row is because sometimes the row matches the value of the column, so when the script runs it's deleting my headers.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the code that I am using

```
function removeDuplicates2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("data");
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = vA[0].indexOf('Campaign Name')
  var list = new Map()
  var rows = [];
  vA.reverse().forEach(function(e,i){
    if (list.get(e[col])){rows.push((vA.length-i))}else{list.set(e[col],(vA.length-i))}
  })
  rows.forEach(x => sh.deleteRow(x))
}
```

Comment: Tried `.offset()`?

Answer (score 0):

#### If you only have one header row and data starts on row 2

```
var [hA, ...vA] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
```

vA no longer contains header

You could also shift the header off.